# iOS and disabling keyboard search or enter key

Tags: ios, keyboard

Is there any way to disable the keyboard's search or enter buttons in iOS?

I'd like to disable these while the text in my `UISearchBar` is too short to commit a search.

Answer (score 13):

It's worth noting that you can change `enablesReturnKeyAutomatically` on the text field, this will cause the return/done key to be disabled when there is no text in the text field.

> // default is NO (when YES, will automatically disable return key when
>   text widget has zero-length contents, and will automatically enable
>   when text widget has non-zero-length contents)

However as SK9 has I'm sure noticed you can't specify rules for when it should be enabled and disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any class named UISearchView - did you mean UISearchBar? If so, keep reading...

You can't disable (gray out) the button programmatically. Implement the `searchBar:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` method on the `UISearchBarDelegate` to check for the replacement text @"\n" (thats the return key press) and if they have entered enough text to allow it to search, and do nothing if they haven't.

If you ***really*** want to disable the return key, you can build your own keyboard view (with no framework keyboard to inherit from to get existing functionality) and return it from the inputView property of a `UITextView` (which means building your own search view as well)

Comment: The problem with building your own keyboard view is that you've to think of all localizations. It is no trivial task. Actually I think there are companies building them as products. :)

Comment: It's not a task for the faint of heart, thats for sure. But it's the only way I can think of to get the exact behavior you're looking for.

Comment: +1 I agree. There is no way to disable the button in the framework's keyboard.

Comment: Here's a hacky solution, but it might work. Create a class that inherits from `UISearchView`, and override the text property to return 'nil' unless the number of characters is > 3 (or whatever). In theory, that should cause the 'done' key to be disabled. Alternatively, create your own `UISearchView` which does *not* inherit from `UISearchBar`, and you can definitely use that hack to disable the keyboard in the `UITextField` of the custom `UISearchView`

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple solution to this with no UI hacks, no accessing Apple private apis and such. Simply add this to viewDidLoad.

```
        yourSearchBar.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = true
```

As per Apples documentation:

> If you set it to true, the keyboard disables the Return key when the text entry area contains no text. As soon as the user enters some text, the Return key is automatically enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it possible to remove buttons of the default UIKeyboard.

For more information, including some URL's see:

[Disabling keys on keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591603/disabling-keys-on-keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

enablesReturnKeyAutomatically to YES if you are using on uitextfield.It works for me.

textField.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = YES / NO